# Latest (or at least non-ancient) Chromium binary?

Tags: chrome, binary, puppy-linux

I've recently been migrating to Puppy Linux (last OS was Ubuntu,) and the only version of Chromium currently available is about as old as the one in the Ubuntu repositories.

I <strike>really suck at</strike> have not had much luck with compiling others' code (I can never manage to get all the build dependencies most of the time,) and the Chromium Project specifically states that it has a ton of unusual dependencies. This wouldn't be much of an issue on a system like Ubuntu or even Arch Linux, because the Chromium project was nice enough to provide the exact command required to fetch all the build dependencies, but with Puppy Linux, you're pretty much dead in the water.
(I know that Puppy Linux has some support for .deb packages, but even the built chromium has an annoying number of dependencies, and I don't want to have to try to round them all up.)

I was just wondering if there's anywhere that I can get EITHER-

- A standalone 32-bit (i686 build preferred) Debian package for Chromium 23 or higher
- A Chromium version 23 or higher .pet file

If someone manages to find/make the second one, I would be *extremely* grateful.

Comment: Why not try Gentoo Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Just installed Chromium 20 on Puppy Linux 5.2.8 Lupu (based on Ubuntu Lucid) from...
    http://distro.ibiblio.org/puppylinux/pet-packages-lucid

Prefer Chromium (open source community supported version of Chrome) since it does **not** auto-update, auto-track or include Adobe Flash (though the plugin is easily added).

Running on several single-core machines...

- Chromium 10 on Puppy  Linux 5.2.8 Lupu  (800MHz, 512MiB RAM)
- Chromium 18 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 Lucid (2.6GHz, 1.23GiB RAM)
- Chromium 20 on Puppy  Linux 5.2.8 Lupu  (2.7GHz, 768MiB RAM)

As a former Firefox devotee, I find any and all of these faster, more reliable and more "well behaved." No huge differences in performance or functionality between them. Just more polish and incremental improvements with each new version. Run the newest version with a .pet for your version of Puppy and that runs well on your hardware.

That said, being built from Ubuntu 10.04, have found Puppy 528 Lupu to run best on my roughly 5-10yo hardware. The Puppy 5.3+ versions are built with newer kernels and video drivers so expect newer hardware.

The Ibiblio site is one of the best sources of Puppy-Linux (.pet) packages.

Though previous version of Puppy, 5.2.2 Wary, runs just fine on my 1999 Toshiba 4030CDT Laptop with 300MHz CPU and 64MiB RAM, Chromium, like all other major browsers, is just too much for it.

**PUPPY RESOURCES**

- [Puppy Linux Lucid (Lupu) Downloads](http://distro.ibiblio.org/puppylinux/pet-packages-lucid)
- [Puppy Linux Forum (one-stop-shop for all things Puppy)](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/)

More versions...

- from [PuppyLinux: chromium](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/chromium) ...

  - [Chromium 27 for Precise, Slacko (and possibly Lucid)](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=84349)

    - packaged by [JamesTheAwesomeDude](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/JamesTheAwesomeDude)
  - [Chromium 22 & 25 for Slacko & Precise](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=81351)

    - packaged by [peebee](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/peebee)

Comment: For what I need, it must be version 22 or higher. Sorry.